# Proxy Issues while Dumping Data into CosmosDB from Dataframe using intelliJ

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, intellij-idea, azure-cosmosdb

I have to dump json data into cosmosDB from spark dataframe using scala and intelliJ.
I am reading a csv file from my local machine and converting it into json format. Now I have to dump this json data into cosmosDB collection.

Spark version is 2.2.0 and scala version is 2.11.8

Below is the code which I wrote in IntelliJ with scala for fetching a csv file from my local machine and convert it into a json file.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config 

object DataLoadConversion {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    System.setProperty("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/spark-warehouse")
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("DataConversion").getOrCreate()

    val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("quote", "\"")
      .option("escape", "\"")
      .option("delimiter", ",")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
      .option("inferSchema","true")
      .load("file:///C:/Users/an/Desktop/ct_temp.csv")

    val finalDf = df.select(df("history_temp_id").as("NUM"),df("history_temp_time").as("TIME"))

    val jsonData = finalDf.select("NUM", "TIME").toJSON
    jsonData.show(2)


    // COSMOS DB Write configuration

    val writeConfig = Config(Map(
      "Endpoint" -> "https://cosms.documents.azure.com:443/",
      "Masterkey" -> "YOUR-KEY-HERE",  //provided primary key
      "Database" -> "DBName", //provided with DB name
      "Collection" -> "Collection", //provided with collection name
      ))

    // Write to Cosmos DB from the DataFrame
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
    jsonData.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).cosmosDB(writeConfig)

  }
```

Below is the build.sbt file

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.5.0",
 
)
libraryDependencies += "com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.2.0_2.11" % "1.1.1" % "provided" exclude("org.apache.spark", "spark-core_2.10")
```

Added cosmosDB dependency to the build.sbt file.

I am new to Spark and Scala. please let me know what all steps to be followed to get connected with cosmos DB from intelliJ with spark and scala?

Build is successful but I am getting below error while running the code.

```
19/07/10 16:32:41 INFO DocumentClient: Initializing DocumentClient with serviceEndpoint [https://cosms.documents.azure.com/], ConnectionPolicy [ConnectionPolicy [requestTimeout=60, mediaRequestTimeout=300, connectionMode=Gateway, mediaReadMode=Buffered, maxPoolSize=400, idleConnectionTimeout=60, userAgentSuffix= SparkConnector/2.2.0_2.11-1.1.1, retryOptions=com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.RetryOptions@1ef5cde4, enableEndpointDiscovery=true, preferredLocations=[Japan East]]], ConsistencyLevel [Session]
19/07/10 16:33:03 WARN DocumentClient: Failed to retrieve database account information. org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to cosms.documents.azure.com:443 [cosms.documents.azure.com/13.78.51.35] failed: Connection timed out: connect
......
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Http client execution failed.
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.internal.GatewayProxy.performGetRequest(GatewayProxy.java:244)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.internal.GatewayProxy.doRead(GatewayProxy.java:93)
```

If I am connecting out of my office network this is working, but when I my machine is connected with office network i am getting above error.
I have tried with configuring proxy settings in below shown page. Settings>>> Proxy settings.

[image]

If i try the same end point in chrome i am getting below error.

```
 {"code":"Unauthorized","message":"Required Header authorization is missing. Ensure a valid Authorization token is passed.\r\nActivityId: 54999e41-179e-4877-b8bf-f2c2a33280fd, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.5.1"}
```

how to resolve this? how to bypass proxy from office network?

Comment: You need to add dependency for cosmosDB https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark

Comment: I am using *build.sbt* file to add dependencies.

Comment: did you add spark cosmosDB dependency in built.sbt file ?

Comment: @Shankar Koirala : Yes I have added the cosmos DB dependency as below.  `libraryDependencies += "com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.2.0_2.11" % "1.1.1" % "provided" exclude("org.apache.spark", "spark-core_2.10")`

Comment: Updated the question with the error which I am getting while running the code